# Google data studio - group metrics into folders

Tags: looker-studio

I have 10 plus metrics in Google dashboard and I would like to group/put them into separate folder. Please take a look at the screen below.

While goggling I haven't found a method. Please let me know if this is possible.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature is currently **NOT** implemented. Regarding having the required fields in a specific order, one way is to add a prefix to each of the respective fields such as `rev_`, `sub_`.

I had a quick look through the [Issue Tracker](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7340016) (which also houses **Feature** Requests) and there were two requests (*vote* on existing feature requests by clicking on the *star* icon on the top left).

### 1) [Folders for Data Fields (Dimension & Metrics)](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67647436)

[image]

### 2) [Folders for the Measures and Metrics](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158850915)

[image]